# Adding a footer View to a multi-column GridView in Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

Is it possible to add a footer View to a GridView (which has multiple columns) that behaves like a footer of a ListView? So this footer View (e.g. a pager view) appears only when the user scrolls to the bottom of the GridView, and it has the width of the whole screen, not only 1 grid element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sorry, `GridView` does not offer this sort of capability.

You mention using this for a "pager view". If, by that, you mean a "click here for more" entry, I'd just lazy-load the data once the end of the current grid data is reached. My [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) handles that, and while I have not tried it with `GridView`, it may work -- leastways, I think it should.

Answer (score 4):

In the gridview adapter you can do this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (footerView == null) ? super.getCount() : super.getCount() + 1;
}

public void setFooterView(View v) {
    footerView = v;
}

// create a new view item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (footerView != null && position == getCount()-1) {
        return footerView;
    }
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater lyinflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = lyinflater.inflate(getLayoutItemId(), null);
        ...
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        ...
        convertView = view;
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    ...
    return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT**
*Sorry I did not read the last part*

> and it has the width of the whole screen

Comment: Sorry... after try your answer it's a bug :/ ....  it's create many footerViews ...

Comment: To solve the bug  by adding this code:                          if (convertView!=null && convertView.findViewById(R.id.footerView) != null) {
                convertView = null;
            }